# Virtual Machine Live Use Log

Tags: virtual-machine

I work in an organisation in which numerous members of staff, often in different locations, have access to a number of virtual machines (running Windows) from their personal laptops.

A current issue is that no-one knows if anyone is using a particular machine, and people will be logged out whilst they are working, due to others trying to log in.

Are there any free to use services, or ideally, code methods I could implement myself, that can produce a live 'notice board' style log of if any users are logged in to a particular machine? I.e

======================================

Virtual Machine 1: --------

Virtual Machine 2: User_x

Virtual Machine 3: User_y

Virtual Machine 4: --------

======================================

It would need to be accessible by every user in the organisation. We have a 'sharepoint' hosted by Microsoft, which would be an ideal location for this noticeboard.

An alternative would be some sort of query that could be passed by someone wishing to use a particular machine, something that could be pasted in to the command prompt specifying a particular virtual machine, which simply returns whether the machine is in use or not - ideally returning who is using it.